# browserHistory: React router not finding path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I'm trying to use browserHistory and add parameters to the path, but when adding parameters to my path I'm unable to locate the page because the path where the browser is looking is incorrect because it's adding 'AddAmendLeague' in front of the url.

(http://localhost:8080/Home) What the path should be:

[image]

(http://localhost:8080/AddAmendLeague/1) Now the browser can't find my client.js:

[image]

```
ReactDOM.render(<Router history={browserHistory }>
                <Route path='*' component={Layout}>
                    <IndexRoute         component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="LeagueList" component={LeagueList}/> 
                    <Route path="/AddAmendLeague/:LeagueID" component={AddAmendLeague}/>
                </Route>

            </Router>, app);
```

index.html

```
<script src="client.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Sorry if this is a silly mistake.

Not too sure if you need my package.JSON

Package.JSON

```
{
  "name": "bableandtypescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot --watch --history-api-fallback"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "debug": "^2.3.2",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
    "flux": "^3.0.0",
    "history": "^4.3.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "mysql": "^2.12.0",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "radium": "^0.18.1",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "undebug": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "websocket": "^1.0.23"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question right. But maybe you should use the hashhistory instead of the browserhistory for your routing https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#hashhistory

Then you could use an url with a hash # tag (http://localhost:8080/#/AddAmendLeague/1)

If you want nice urls '/' with browserHistory you should also configure your server to handle this urls https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#configuring-your-server

Comment: Hi, hashHistory does work but I'm trying to keep nice looking URL's and browserhistory provides that. Does browserhistory routes work differently than hashHistory?

Comment: based on your question it would seem that this line of code is not clear to you. <Route path="/AddAmendLeague/:LeagueID" component={AddAmendLeague}/> this line says you will go to AddAmendLeague and have a param called LeagueID. Am I not understanding your question?

Comment: wel if you want nice urls with browserHistory you should also configure your server (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#configuring-your-server)